# SQL CASE statement with multiple LIKE options

Tags: sql, insert, case

I'm trying to use the USER_AGENT to determine if a user clicking my link is using a mobile device. Every click creates a row in my table, and I'm trying to insert either a "1" if the user is on mobile, or a "0" if he/she is not.

I've come up with the following SQL statement. Would this work? Is there any way to combine all those cases into a single line, as they all result in the same value (1)? And how could I optimize this for speed? I'm open to any suggestions. Thank you!

```
INSERT INTO click_table(mobile_agent)
VALUES
(
    CASE
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%mobi%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%iphone%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%ipad%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%android%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%blackberry%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%blazer%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%bolt%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%symbianos%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%doris%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%dorothy%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%fennec%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%gobrowser%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%iemobile%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%iris%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%maemo%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%mib%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%minimo%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%netfront%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%mini%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%semc%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%skyfire%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%teashark%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%teleca%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%uzardweb%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%docomo%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%vodafone%' THEN '1'
        when user_agent_string LIKE '%playbook%' THEN '1'
        else '0'
    END
);
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? It should be possible to combine these into a single `LIKE ANY(%<term>%,%<term>%)` or `LIKE IN (%<term>%,%<term>%...)` or `REGEXP '<term>|<term>|<term>'` depending on your DB.

Comment: Is it possible to do any of this logic before sql? As in whenever you are going to store the user_agent_string can you do the search in your code and put it into the table directly then?

Comment: Or you can also create a seperate table that holds all the valid string so that you can just go to it and search user_agent_string inside the values of that table. This way your query will look much simpler. I am not sure whether this would be an improvement in terms of speed though